# Removing part of text before and after specific character in SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, text

I have a table called `item` and a column `description`. The values of description are like

```
 243~Test Value~~11~123
```

How do I get only `Test Value` ? I want to drop the part of text before `~` and after `~~` using a T-SQL query.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Description, CHARINDEX ('~', Description, 1)+1, CHARINDEX ('~~', Description, 1)-CHARINDEX ('~', Description, 1)-1) 
FROM Item
```